# How to enable system restart on BSOD from commandline

Tags: windows-server-2003, hyper-v, windows, bsod

I got an Hyper-v core box and I need to turn automatic restart on. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The configuration is held in the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl\AutoReboot
```

With a setting of either 1 (AutoReboot on) or 0 (AutoReboot off)

The following command should enable it:

```
reg add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl\ /v AutoReboot /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Comment: I would add to this that if you're having crashes often enough that you want to turn this on you have **more serious problems** than the fact that your system isn't rebooting itself after a crash.  Find and fix the problem that is causing your crash!

Comment: I need to move guest OSes from a distance. Then I'll take care about BSOD.

Comment: Look in the BIOS settings as well - your server needs to know to turn on after a power failure.

Comment: It's "Always ON" & tested. Thanks.

Comment: @newmanth - Good catch, thanks. That was a Google job!